# After successfully installing Magento 2.2.2 I can't connect to admin

Tags: magento2.2.2, https

I installed successfully Magento, but I can't connect to admin.

I am suspecting that this is because I chose HTTPS for both `store` and `admin` page while installing. I can connect to the store if I use HTTP but I can't with HTTPS.

But unfortunately I can't choose HTTP in admin, it reverts back to HTTPS, and I can't connect after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have ssl installed in your server you are not able to access any page by using https . In order to resolve your issue if you have access in database and go to core_config_data table change your setting on value section and clear cache ,then run admin url .

Comment: Yes, you are right. I updated the core_config_data table accordingly and now I can access the admin using `HTTP`. However I think I have SSLfor the domain, just not enabled. Do I need to do any further actions in order to enable HTTPS in Magento (besides reverting the changes in core_config_table)?

Comment: It depends what you actually looking for :
1. If you are deploying in live environment  you need to purchase  SSL certificate or 
2. if do it just for test you can generate self signed  ssl this link might help you   https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04.